# Problem with left inverse logic

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

New to linear algebra. I'm reading Mike X Cohens book on Linear Algebra, "Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code".

I don't follow the logic behind the left inverse. I will try to explain what I mean using matrix T below, a tall matrix with dimensions 3*2 (p.346 in the book)

1. I transpose T and matrix multiply it by itself, returns a square matrix 2*2
2. I get the invers of that square matrix above by:

- compute the determinant,
- swap diagonal elements,
- multiply off-diagonal elements by -1 and
- divide by the determinant.

3. So far so good, but here comes the part I don't understand.
   To get the left inverse, I should multiply the inverse of the square matrix by T transposed.

In my head, this is not valid matrix multiplication since the inverse of the square matrix is 2*2 and the T transpose is 2*3 - inner dimensions dosen't match?

4. The resulting matrix, the left inverse

## 1.

$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$T*T^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 9 \\
9 & 29 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

## 2.

$(T^T*T)^{-1}$ = 1/6 * [[29,-9],[-9,3]]

## 3.

$(T^T*T)^-1$ * $T^T$ = $T^{-L}$

## 4.

$T^{-L}$ = $(T^T*T)^{-1}$ * $T^T$ = 1/6 [ [11,-3],[2,0], [-7,3] ]

$T^{-L}$*T = 1/6 [ [6,0], [0,6] ] # Returns the identity matrix

I would appricate if someone could explain why it's valid matrix multiplication and perhaps write it out so I grasp this step in the algorithm.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), in particular to display matrices, otherwise the question is almost unreadable.

Comment: @DavidM Thanks - I tried it, but I didn't get the superscript to work "x^2"?

Comment: Did you follow the link that David provided?

Comment: I did, but apparently I did not do it right.

Comment: @Henri Superscripts are easy: "dollar sign x^2 dollar sign" gives $x^2$. But your edit doesn't seem to have used mathjax at all.

Comment: @Henri: Note that in the triple-quoted environment you used for item $4$., everything is just shown verbatim, including dollar signs and math formatting. You need to remove those triple quotes.

Comment: it's valid because you should multiply from left, hence the left inverse; [2*2 x 2*3] and the inner blocks match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the theory before jumping into the particular case. If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix where $m \ne n$ then its left inverse is a matrix, say $A_L$, such that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
A_L A = I_n,
\end{equation}
where $I_n$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix. Likewise, $A_R$ is its right inverse if
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
AA_R = I_m,
\end{equation}
where $I_m$ is an $m \times m$ identity matrix. Before proceeding kindly convince yourself that the dimensions of the identity matrices in equations (1) and (2) are correct.

Let us now try to find what $A_L$ is. Since $A$ is not a square matrix, it does not have the usual inverse. We can form a square matrix from $A$ in two ways. $A^TA$ will give an $n \times n$ matrix while $AA^T$ will result in an $m \times m$ matrix. If $AA^T$ is not singular, then its inverse will exist and
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
AA^T (AA^T)^{-1} = I_m \Rightarrow A (A^T (AA^T)^{-1}) = I_m.
\end{equation}
Comparing with equation (2) we get
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
A_R = A^T (AA^T)^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Likewise, if $A^TA$ is not singular, $(A^TA)^{-1}$ will exist and
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
(A^T A)^{-1}A^TA = I_n.
\end{equation}
Comparing with equation (1) we get
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
A_L = (A^T A)^{-1}A.
\end{equation}
In your case,
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
AA^T = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 9 \\ 9 & 29\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation},
\begin{equation}\tag{9}
(AA^T)^{-1} = \frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}29 & -9 \\ -9 & 3\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}\tag{10}
A_R = \frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}11 & -3 \\ 2 & 0 \\ -7 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
We now check,
\begin{equation}\tag{11}
AA_R = I_2.
\end{equation}
You can compute $A_L$ using equation (1).

Comment: thanks for the response. I made a misstake thou when I defined my matrix T. I used logic from nympy arrays in python. Now I've adjusted it and rows and columns is swaped.